# Need help to load the page content on button click

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="samepage.php"><img src="button.png"></a>
<div>
//page content, database queries, calculations etc
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want to load DIV content at page open, only i want load this DIV when i press button,

is there any technique to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should seperate the code in the div into antorher file. Than using jQuery ajax functions will do it.

[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

[jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

If this is not the case, u can use a flag in the link like (mypage.php?process=true).For example if page is loaded like this:

mypage.php

your php code should skip till the end with this code.

```
if(isset($_GET['process'])
{
 //you do page content, database queries, calculations etc
}
else
{
 //skip
}
```

And your link in the button should be like this:

```
a href="samepage.php?process=ture"
```

Comment: I added some other method for your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, the it can be easily done as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#yourDivId").click(function() {
     //load content from some page
     $("#divIdToLoadContentAt").load("some_page.php");
  });
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: but my content is in same page in DIV

Comment: can i load my DIV like this, 
$("#divIdToLoadContentAt").load();

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, it's colloquially called AJAX. Using JavaScript, you can make an asynchronous request for the contents of `samepage.php` and feed it into the `div`.

Comment: i need to put my whole content in same page.

Comment: means i can call my same page DIV with AJAX also?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, but from how I understand it, yes, you can.

Comment: ok, fine i'll call my DIV with AJAX, but on page load i want to execute my page till my image button (if u see my given code), n sry for english :)